# Creating dynamic SVG Elements with JavaScript but attributes have no effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, typescript

I'm trying to write a jQuery plugin that I already wrote in es5, now I want to refactor into TypeScript.

I am trying to create an `<svg>` element and then also create a `<rect>` element, and then append `<rect>` inside of `<svg>`, and then finally append `<svg>` to DOM.

Everything in the DOM seems fine, all the elements and attributes are there, but for some reason the SVG is not being rendered.

If I copy the generated element from the DOM and past it in my `index.html` file as a static element, it renders fine. (as seen Here)

TS:

```
        // create the svg
        let svgSquare = document.createElementNS('http://http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');

        const clickClass = clickAnimationName.length ? `shape-${shapeLayerNum}-click-${clickAnimationName}` : '';
        const mouseEnterClass = mouseEnterAnimationName.length ? `shape-${shapeLayerNum}-mouse-enter-${mouseEnterAnimationName}` : '';
        const mouseLeaveClass = mouseLeaveAnimationName.length ? `shape-${shapeLayerNum}-mouse-leave-${mouseLeaveAnimationName}` : '';

        const svgSquareClasses = `${clickClass} ${mouseEnterClass} ${mouseLeaveClass}`;

        // add svg classes
        // svgSquare.setAttribute('class', svgSquareClasses);

        // set svg attributes
        svgSquare.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");

        svgSquare.setAttribute('viewBox', `0 0 ${shapeScale/2} ${shapeScale/2}`);
        svgSquare.setAttribute('fill', shapeConfig[`shape-${shapeLayerNum}-background`]);
        svgSquare.setAttribute('stroke', 'black');
        svgSquare.setAttribute('stroke-width', `${shapeScale/100}px`);

        // sizing/centering
        svgSquare.setAttribute('z-index', shapeConfig[`shape-${shapeLayerNum}-zIndex`]);
        svgSquare.setAttribute('width', `${(shapeScale) + (shapeSpacing*2)}px`);
        svgSquare.setAttribute('height', `${(shapeScale) + (shapeSpacing*2)}px`);

        svgSquare.setAttribute('style', `margin-left: ${shapeMarginLeft}px; margin-top: ${shapeMarginTop}px;`);

        // create the square rect
        let polySquare = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'rect');
        polySquare.setAttribute('width', `${(shapeWidth/2 - (shapeSpacing*2))}`);
        polySquare.setAttribute('height', `${(shapeHeight/2) - (shapeSpacing*2)}`);
        polySquare.setAttribute('x', `${shapeSpacing/2}`);
        polySquare.setAttribute('y', `${shapeSpacing/2}`);

        // rect polygon to svg
        svgSquare.appendChild(polySquare);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've a typo in the namespace - http:// should only be in there once

```
  let svgSquare = document.createElementNS('http://http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
```